# How I can save a sheet as pdf and save a folder

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I have  a code here to save file as pdf, at the same time, I want make a folder with named cell value and save file in that folder

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Sheet3.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("A2").Value & "-" & Sheet1.Range("B2").Value, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True


End Sub
```

Comment: Great! And the question is?

Comment: Which cell contains the new folder name?  Or what is the new folder name meant to look like?  At the moment you are using `ActiveWorkbook.Path` but what do you **want** to use?

Answer (score 0):

To create the folder you need to use `MkDir`

```
Dim folder As String

folder = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheet1.Range("A2").Value
MkDir folder 'this makes the folder

Sheet3.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, _
Filename:=folder & "\" & Sheet1.Range("B2").Value 'saves the file in that folder
```

If there is a chance of creating a folder/file with the same name I'd add in some If/Then statements to check if the folder/file exists first or not.